# Hacer una busqueda en un dataframe con varias condicionantes en otro dataframe en r

Tags: r

Tengo 2 df, el primero "OBS" (la clase de period es date)

```
lon <- c(-112.3036, -112.2490, -112.3186, -112.3604, -112.3706, -112.3188)
lat <- c(25.90607, 25.88545, 25.98330, 26.09447, 26.08657, 25.98420)
period <- c("2015-05-13", "2015-05-13", "2015-05-13", "2015-05-13", "2015-05-13", "2015-05-14")
sst <- c(17, 18 ,17, 21, 21, 17)
```

el segundo "SAT" (la clase de period es date)

```
lon <- c(-112.286, -112.286, -112.3036, -112.286, -112.3188, -112.286)
lat <- c(24.97255, 24.97255, 25.90607, 24.97255, 25.98420, 24.97255)
period <- c("2015-05-01", "2015-05-02", "2015-05-13", "2015-05-04", "2015-05-14", "2015-05-06")
remp<- c(20.755, 21.495, 21.745, 21.920, NA, 21.520)
```

Estoy intentando de que SOLO cuando coincidan los valores de OBS$lon, OBS$lat & OBS$period en el df SAT, me cree una columna en el df OBS con el valor de SAT$remp incluyendo si tiene NA´s

intente con este bucle pero no parece ser la mejor opción

```
for (k in 1:length(OBS)) {
   OBS$comp <- ifelse(c(SAT$lat == OBS$lat, SAT$lon == OBS$lon & SAT$period == OBS$period), c(SAT$remp), NA")
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido user299064 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible resolverlo con un enfoque iterativo, como el que has intentado, pero ciertamente tu código está lejos de resolverlo y en R, en muchas oportunidades (como ésta), usar este enfoque es complejo e innecesario. Lo que buscas es lo que en la lógica de base de datos relacionales se conoce como un **LEFT JOIN**, es decir, todas las filas de un `data.frame` más los datos del segundo `data.frame` que coincidan en ciertos argumentos con el primero. En R base puedes lograrlo así:

```
merge(OBS, SAT, by=c("lon", "lat", "period"), all.x = TRUE)

        lon      lat     period sst   temp
1 -112.3706 26.08657 2015-05-13  21     NA
2 -112.3604 26.09447 2015-05-13  21     NA
3 -112.3188 25.98420 2015-05-14  17     NA
4 -112.3186 25.98330 2015-05-13  17     NA
5 -112.3036 25.90607 2015-05-13  17 21.745
6 -112.2490 25.88545 2015-05-13  18     NA
```

Es decir, todas las filas de `OBS` (`all.x = TRUE`) y las columnas de `SAT` que coincidan en `by=c("lon", "lat", "period")`.

Otra forma, si usarás `tidyverse` sería:

```
library(tidyverse)

OBS %>% 
  left_join(SAT, by=c("lon", "lat", "period"))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, este consejo me ha ayudado mucho a verlo desde otro enfoque